# How to read/write data with BLE and `react-native-ble-plx`?

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ble-plx

I successfully setup [`react-native-ble-plx` to a handle BLE](https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx) device.

I don't have any prior experience working with bluetooth. From my understanding and after reading the documentation, here is how I am supposed to read some informations from the bluetooth device.

```js
// Connect to the device
const connectedDevice = await device.connect();

// Discover all services and characteristics
const servicesAndCharacteristics = await connectedDevice.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics();

// let's say I discovered these UUID
const SERVICE_UUID = '0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb';
const CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = '00002a23-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb';

// Writing command
const characteristic1 = await servicesAndCharacteristics.writeCharacteristicWithResponseForService(SERVICE_UUID, CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, CMD_GET_INFO);

// Reading the response
const response1 = await characteristic1.read();
console.log(response1.value); // Logs the response
```

I received this documentation from the firmware developer of the bluetooth device.

> After establishing Bluetooth communication between the app and the controller, the app can retrieve device information using `CMD_GET_INFO`. At this stage, direct read-and-write to the device are not yet possible. The app needs to send the `CMD_ENTER_PRO` command and wait for the controller to respond with 'Success' before it can proceed to send other commands.

I don't understand this part

> the app can **retrieve device information using CMD_GET_INFO**

I thought communication for BLE uses `Service UUID` and  `Characteristic UUID`.
On the entire documentation i have zero mention about `UUID`'s.
Only using `CMD_GET_INFO`, but how?

I tried every combinaison of `SERVICE_UUID`, and `CHARACTERISTIC_UUID` discovered with `discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics`, used plain string for `CMD_GET_INFO` or `base64.encode`.

Every-time I encounter this kind of error:

> Failed to connect Characteristic xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx read failed for device

#### Questions:

- What informations would I need to "CRUD" data on the device? (*I have a web background so for me it's reading a classic REST api documentation*).
- Does it make sense if I ask to give examples how how to use `SERVICE_UUID` and `CHARACTERISTIC_UUID`.

I don't understand if the errors are coming from my code, or a broken build of the firmware.

---

**Edit**
Following @Michael answer I downloaded `nRF Connect`.

It's great to debug. I think the errors are not from my implementation in React Native but from the device it self because I have this error:

[image: BLE timeout]

Comment: Can you give us more information about the BLE device, maybe even a link the documentation? Maybe try using a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to test the BLE device first, just to eliminate problems in your implementation. Once you manage to establish a connection and are able to get information from the device you can move on to your own app

Comment: I downloaded LightBlue for doing the opposite : creating a virtal Bluetooth device from my phone and test my code.  

Thank you for the "nRF Connect" recommandation! I will try then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon investigating, I discovered that my issue is related to the Bluetooth firmware.

Daniel explains it quite clearly in this video.
https://youtu.be/UuHLPsjp6fM?si=iHAB80aVruJHUDQM&t=895

> **`Services UUID` and `Characteristics UUID` comes from your device manual or your firmware engineer.**

So, i "just" need to ask a better documentation.